# ¿Cómo puedo instalar la última version de perl v5.28 en conda?

Tags: perl, control-de-versiones

Estoy intentando correr unos análisis y me da error por la version de perl:

```
$ bowtie2 --threads 4 --local --no-unal \
          -x /home/me/workspace/referencegenome/sturnus_relictumgenome.fasta \
          -q -k 1 --al aligned_reads.fastq \
          -U /home/me/workspace/*.fasta > aligned_host_parasite.sam
**perl: symbol lookup error:**
   /var/bin/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so:
   undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
```

He intentado actualizar la versión de perl mediante `conda update perl` o `conda install -c anaconda perl` pero nada.

Al escribir el comando `conda search perl` las versiones disponibles que me salen son :

```
# Name                  Version           Build  Channel             
perl                     5.26.0      hae598fd_0  pkgs/main           
perl                     5.26.2      h14c3975_0  pkgs/main
```

Alguno/a sabría como poder actualiza perl a su version mas nueva en conda?

Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Algo que siempre puedes hacer es instalar Perl en tu directorio local, y no depender del Perl del sistema.

Con herramientas como perlbrew o plenv puedes instalar la versión que quieras, en tu directorio local, y a partir de ese momento usarlo o des/activarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario. He intentado instalarme perlbrew pero me da error tambien : /home/luz_garcia_longoria/miniconda3/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /var/bin/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck